# Detected dubious ownership in repository

Tags: git, docker, terraform

I am trying to initialize Terraform inside a Docker container in my shell script, like so:

```
terraform() {
  docker run --rm -e "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" \
    -e "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" \
    -e "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN:-""}" \
    -e "AWS_REGION=$AWS_REGION" \
    -e "TF_IN_AUTOMATION=true" \
    -v "$HOME/.kube:/root/.kube" \
    -v "$PWD:/work" -w /work "$TERRAFORM_DOCKER_IMAGE" "$@"
}

initialize_terraform() {
  docker build -f "$(dirname "$0")/terraform.Dockerfile" -t "$TERRAFORM_DOCKER_IMAGE" . && \
  &>/dev/null pushd "$INFRA_PATH"
  terraform init \
    -backend-config="bucket=$TERRAFORM_S3_BUCKET" \
    -backend-config="key=$TERRAFORM_S3_KEY"
}
```

I have other functions which run a similar process, for example:

```
aws() {
  docker run --rm -e "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" \
    -e "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" \
    -e "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN:-""}" \
    -e "AWS_REGION=$AWS_REGION" \
    -v "$PWD:/work" \
    -v "$HOME/.kube/config:/root/.kube/config" \
    -v "/tmp:/tmp" \
    -w /work \
    "$AWS_DOCKER_IMAGE" "$@"

aws eks list-clusters
```

The above, uses the the directory `~/Project:/work`.

It is only when I run the `initialize_terraform` function that I get the error:

```
╷
│ Error: Failed to download module
│
│ Could not download module "explore-california-vpc" (cluster.tf:39) source
│ code from
│ "git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc?ref=v5.1.1":
│ error downloading
│ 'https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc?ref=v5.1.1':
│ /usr/bin/git exited with 128: fatal: detected dubious ownership in
│ repository at '/work/.terraform/modules/explore-california-vpc'
│ To add an exception for this directory, call:
│
│       git config --global --add safe.directory
│ /work/.terraform/modules/explore-california-vpc
│ .
╵
```

By looking at other posts that mention the same error, many suggest using `git config --global --add safe.directory /work/.terraform/modules/explore-california-vpc`, but I don't believe this is the solution to my error, since `/work` is the mount in the Docker container.

I noticed that when running other commands, such as `aws`, there's no error. The error only occurs when using the `initialize_terraform` function and the difference here is that the current directory is changed to `$INFRA_PATH`. In contrast to the path used by `aws`, terraform ends up using `~/Project/infra:/work`.

I've tried running the script without changing the directory, but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: git's complaining that the repo is owned by a different user (i.e. the uid of your user on the host system). To fix that, you need to either make the uid's match, change the ownership inside the container, or override git's self check (what that command is doing).

Comment: OK, if the command is ```git config --global --add safe.directory /work/.terraform/modules/explore-california-vpc```, I get an error because ```/work``` is not a local directory, but the mount on the container.

Comment: Are you trying to run that command on the host system, instead of inside the container? The problem is that git _inside_ the container is unhappy because the user that's running it in the container (root?) isn't the same as the user that owns the repo (presumably your user on the host system). Changing the config of git on the host system isn't going to affect git inside the container.

Comment: Yes, I do see what you're saying. I'm looking into running it inside the container. Since I'm pretty new at this I'm having Bing help me but it looks like it's not doing much in that regard. I modified ```terraform()``` by capturing the body as defined above into ```container_id``` and adding the last two lines, but no luck:

```docker exec $container_id git config --global --add safe.directory /work/.terraform/modules/explore-california-vpc
  
  docker exec $container_id terraform "$@"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the course instructor where I got the project from, which solved my issue:

"Since Terraform modules are downloaded as Git repositories because we are cloning each module into **/work** within the container - the current directory on our host - they will, indeed, have different UNIX file permissions, which Git does not like. We can fix this in two steps:

1. Create a Docker volume called **tfdata** (or any name you'd like):

> docker volume create tfdata

2. Inside of the script, add these two lines underneath the "docker run" statement:

> -v "tfdata:/tfdata"
>
> -e TF_DATA_DIR=/tfdata

This will tell Terraform to download our modules into **/tfdata** (within the container) instead of our current directory, which will avoid the dubious permissions error we're seeing here. As well, because "tfdata" is bind-mounted to a Docker volume, this will allow you to re-use your modules should you run the script multiple times.